# "Cannot read property '$wire' of undefined at Livewire.value" al usar Turbolinks en Laravel Livewire con AdminLTE

Tags: laravel, livewire, adminlte

El error sucede solamente cuando uso Turbolinks en Laravel Livewire con la plantilla AdminLTE, de lo contrario no obtengo ningún error. Cuando cargo la página por primera vez no da ningún error, el error aparece cuando doy clic en otra pestaña de mi aplicación.

[image: resources/js/app.js]

[image: layouts/app.blade.php]

[image: El error de Alpine]

```
--app.blade.php

    @extends('adminlte::page')
@section('title', 'Inicio')

@section('content_header')
    <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold">@yield('titulo-contenido')</h1>
@stop

@section('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
@livewireStyles
@stop

@section('content')
{{$slot}}
@stop

@section('js')
     <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
     @livewireScripts
@stop
```

Comment: El código y mensaje de error van como texto por favor

Comment: Donde estas insertando los estilos y js de livewire?

Comment: como esta en la imagen lo estoy insertando en la configuracion de la adminlte, poniendo true donde dice livewire. pero ahorita lo tengo en layouts/app.blade.php, al final de sus respectivas secciones y obtengo el mismo problema